# Video won't play autoplay with sound HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a video for my website but it won't autoplay till I refresh the page

Tried changing the code but it only work when the audio is muted. when there is audio it doesn't autoplay and I have to refresh the page

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <video  autoplay loop muted width="1900"> 
            <source src="images/video/ad.mp4" type="video/mp4" />  <!-- Declaring it is a video and from where the file should be played from -->
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like it to autoplay when I open the page with audio instead of me refreshing the page for it to play with audio.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? I can't recreate this error. Any mp4 video I use wit this code plays fine for me.

Comment: Is this in happening in Chrome? This kind of sounds like you might be running into [Chrome's autoplay policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) - "Muted autoplay is always allowed. Autoplay with sound is allowed if: User has interacted with the domain...".

Comment: 4.3.1. Try removing muted from the code and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is coming from Googles Autoplay Policy Changes:**

Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:

- Muted autoplay is always allowed.
- Autoplay with sound is allowed if:

  - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
  - On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously play video with sound.
  - On mobile, the user has [added the site to their home screen].
- Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

---

I would think having the user click would be the best solution to unmute an ad. Below is an example using a stock video. Your code is the same just the video url changed and a *basic button was added below the video*.

```js
unmuteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  video.muted = false;
});
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <video muted autoplay loop width="1900" id="video"> 
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />  <!-- Declaring it is a video and from where the file should be played from -->
      </video>
    <button id="unmuteButton">Unmute</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that has been helpful. I have decided to use controls because I can't get it to work. Also having an unmute button makes it look unprofessional in a website.