# How to autoplay local video with iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

There are many solutions out there on how to make youtube/vimeo autoplay a video but they don't seem to work on a local video:

```
<template>
  <section id="vision" class="vision">
    <iframe src="videos/cgi_neutral.mp4?autoplay=1" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
  </section>
</template>
```

This does not autoplay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Video won't play autoplay with sound HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369934/video-wont-play-autoplay-with-sound-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, instead of using an iframe, use a `<video>` tag. (Because its self-hosted on your website, no need to use an iframe) To make it autoplay, just add the "autoplay" attribute.

For Example:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
 <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

For all those for whom `autoplay` attribute doesn't work, it shouldn't. Your video should be either `muted` as well, or there should be any registered action from user before (lick "click"). Otherwise browser won't allow your video to autoplay - which is good, actually.

So your code should like something like that:

```
            <video
                controls
                autoplay
                muted
                width="860"
                height="490"
            >
                <source
                    src="path.mp4"
                    type="video/mp4"
                />
```